# Cordova android javascript execution difficult

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

I have some mysterious behaviour with my javascript code in my cordova android app. The javascript execution becomes anyhow not right executed. The intervals,conditions, timeouts and `clearTimeout` gets manipulated I think. You can see a demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7hp4r6ga/4/) In my browser without the phonegap ready all works well. What can cause this behaiviour I have not only with these app.

**index.js file**

```
    var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <!-- Einstellungen zur Defintion als WebApp -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-content" id="bak" style="width:100%;height:100%;position: absolute;">
<div class="header1">
<p class="score" style="white-space: normal" id="score"></p>
</div>
<p class="go" style="white-space: normal" id="number"></p>
</div>
<script>
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function gameplay() {
    window.location.href='main1.html';  
    }
function onDeviceReady() {

here is the js code you can see in the fiddle

}
</script>
</div>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are your sure Jquery is outside JS folder? And try loading it after cordova.js

Comment: Yes it is and if I load it after cordova it wont change sth. :(